# proving that a problem is in P

Tags: np, p-vs-np, complexity-theory

I read online that this problem is in P:

> Problem = {a^n, where n is a primary number}

I can't find any algorithm that decides if a word `w` in `{a}*` is in `Problem`, can someone help me because I'm not really convinced that this problem can be solved in polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: does being in P have something to do with the length of the input?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: The AKS primality test is in P.